# Limit rotation axes of a bone driven by an IK

Tags: armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to add bones to the standard human metarig to control an exosuit that moves with the leg. The chain of new bones is fixed at the models back, then runs down to the knee. I've tried linking it to the knee so when I pose the leg the exosuit moves with it. Each join in the new chain is a hinge so all bones have 2 axes of rotation locked so they can only move around the hinge line.

However if I attach the IK bone to the knee or even leave it loose as a control the bones in the chain don't respect the rotation locks and spin in all three axes.

Am I missing something, or is there a better way to do this?

I've built the parts in a parametric CAD model so I know the join combo should work.

[image: Bones in edit mode]

[image: Leg posed]

[image: Example of bone twisting off axis]